# Вопрос по схеме строения базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

Вопрос по схеме базы данных

У меня есть база данных для хранения сообщений в мессенджере, как лучше разделить чаты?
Сделать одну таблицу `messages`, и сделать там столбцы `chat_id`, `message_id`, `content`, `author_id` или для каждого чата создавать таблицу с именем `chat_%chat_id%` (например `chat_111`) и в ней сделать столбцы `message_id`, `content`, `author_id`?

Comment: Лучше сначала почитать про нормализацию данных. Хоть что-нибудь...

Comment: Первое, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а нормально что обсалютно все сообщения мессенджера будут хранится в одной таблице? Так сказать в одной куче?

Comment: @Mr.Nom4ik Задам встречный вопрос. А нормально ли, что сообщения от разных пользователей будут храниться "в одной куче"? А сообщения за разные дни "в одной куче"? Может сделаете отдельные таблицы для сообщений разных пользователей, за разные дни и т.д.? Абсурд, нет? Однотипные объекты нормально хранить "в одной куче", если у вас есть поля, по которым вы их можете фильтровать. А вот если бы вы сделали тучу отдельных таблиц, вам было бы очень сложно к ним обращаться. Но иногда так всё же делают, если речь о миллионах записей и "в одной куче" недостаточно места, например.

Comment: @CrazyElf, простите, просто я подумал что если всё будет в одной супер больной таблице, то вдруг сервер будет долго отрабатывать запросы на неё

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Mr.Nom4ik Нет, ну так то ваши рассуждения имеют право на жизнь, но только в случае, если вы физически хотите разделить чаты, например, с целью их поместить в дальнейшем на разные сервера в разные базы и т.п. А если у вас планируется на одном сервере много чатов, то при правильном обслуживании базы (вы создали все нужные индексы в таблицах и т.д.), нормализованная база такой структуры как в первом примере - вполне рабочий вариант. А если будет множество таблиц для разных чатов, то базе от этого будет не легче, а вот вам будет сложнее к ним обращаться.